# I cannot understand what the error is in the build.gradle although i tried everything

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

Because of an error i get from build.gradle file my emulator does not run. I looked it up on google,youtube and forums but I cannot fix this bug. The error I am getting is "Could not find method implementation() for arguments [DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.google.firebase', name='firebase-bom', version='32.3.1', configuration='default'}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler."

build.gradle/app

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms:google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms:google-services'

android {
    namespace "com.example.food"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.food"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1')
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics')
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
        implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
        }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried to change versions but it did not help imo

Comment: That bottom `build.gradle` has `implementation` lines that might not belong there.

Comment: @CommonsWare are you talking about the ones in the dependencies?

Comment: @Korhan_34 yes, please try removing 2 lines below the line `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`

Comment: @VladGuriev now it gives me this error "Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found."

Comment: @Korhan_34 please try adding `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'` instead